# how do i get downloadurl from below code?

Tags: kotlin

Below is the code I checked and it did not work.

I did get not url but get "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@ffbfff5"

I think

```
val url=taskSnapshot.getMetadata()?.getReference()?.getDownloadUrl()?.toString()
```

should be amended but I dont know how to fix.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_PROFILE_FROM_ALBUM && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            var imageUri = data?.data
            val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid 

            FirebaseStorage
                .getInstance()
                .reference
                .child("userProfileImages")
                .child(uid)
                .putFile(imageUri!!)
                .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                    val url = taskSnapshot.getMetadata()?.getReference()?.getDownloadUrl()?.toString()
                    val map = HashMap<String, Any>()
                    map["image"] = url
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("profileImages").document(uid).set(map)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getDownloadUrl` returns [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html), so you should us the API to get its result.

Comment: Sorry but can you tell me which API i should use?